# Missing Scrollbars in Eclipse with PyDev

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse and PyDev installed on my Xubuntu 14.04 workstation.

Whenever I edit a file, the scrollbars for the editor are missing, and the vertical scrollbar has been replaced with a large grey bar the length of the editor on the right side. It's been like this since I first installed it over six months ago.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Eclipse]

The scrollbars for the other modules (like the package explorer) are fine, as you can see on the left side of the screenshot. It appears to be PyDev specific, since if I open a plaintext file, the scrollbars appear correctly.

Any idea what's causing this, or how to fix it?

Comment: Does this happen when you start eclipse from terminal with elevated privilege?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath I just set up a new PyDev/Eclipse instance to run as root, and yes, the problem persists there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in 'Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Overview Ruler Minimap' for the PyDev scroll bar options.

Comment: That worked! Is that a new feature that's just not working for me for some reason?

Comment: It is new, I believe PyDev now defaults to no scroll bars.